# Can I chain views in a constraint layout (End_toStartOf) so that they wrap on a narrow screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm writing a game of hangman in the current version of Android Studio.

At the bottom of the screen I want to have a button for each letter of the alphabet plus a few for other game play, say 30 buttons in total. For portrait screens I'd like this to be, say, 5 rows of 6 buttons, but for landscape 4 rows with 8 buttons (except the last row, obvs). I'd like the actual positions to be set automatically and not to have to move buttons around in code.

I've been playing with the constraint layout, but I can't seem to get the buttons to change rows. I would have thought that this was possible. I've tried chaining, but no luck.

I'm a newbie to Android Studio and watching as many tutorials as possible, but not found an answer to this yet. Happy to supply more details and try suggestions. I'm using Kotlin for code and running AS on Ubuntu FYI.

Comment: Take a look at [FlexBox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) and the [flow helper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) in ConstraintLayout 2.0.

Comment: If you want to create a different layout for the landscape, just create a new layout with the same name under the folder `\res\layout-land` this layout will be used when the phone is in landscape.

Comment: Thanks for those. Will try them both today and report back.